# how to select data from table according to date interval?

Tags: php, sql

how to retrieve all data from table using date interval?

### this is my code

```
<?php
    include '../php_action/db_connect.php';


    $startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
    $enddate = $_POST['enddate'];

    echo 'ORDERS BETWEEN '.$startdate.' and '.$enddate;


    $sql = "SELECT * from orders WHERE order_date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'" ;

    $result=$connect->query($sql);

    while($row=$result->fetch_array())
    {
        echo '<br>'. $row['order_id'] ;
    }


    ?>
```

it isn't working, but when i change it to **where order_id = 1;** *(for example)* it works.

i even tried **where order_date = 2020/03/02;** still not working.

how should i work this out?

Comment: (1) Use prepared queries (2) Use proper date formats (in MySQL, that's `YYYY-MM-DD`)

Comment: im already using proper date formats

Comment: @GMB I believe `/` is a valid separator for month, year, day. `A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts`

Comment: @youssef  `it isn't working` is not clear enough. Could you please describe the behavior and use error reporting? You also, as previously noted, should use parameterized queries. `where order_date = 2020/03/02` wouldn't work because the date is not quoted. Also is the column `date` or `datetime`?

Answer (score 1):

Put a semicolon after the sql statement inside the quotes.

```
  $sql = "SELECT * from orders WHERE order_date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate';" ;
                                                                                  ^^
```

If that doesn't solve it the problem could be a number of things.  You may have your MySql set to StrictDates.  Depending on your setup you may have strict dates requiring additional zeros.  See the following:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

When troubleshooting these I try to insert known good data and then work on identifying on how to get that data to pass through.

Try #1 - attempt this: change to specific dates and add a semi-colon to the end inside the quote:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from orders WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 10:10:10' AND '2020-03-01 10:10:10';" ;
```

If that works you can delete the times to identify if MySQL is in strict mode.  This should help you identify where your issues are.

Comment: it didn't work neither way, any other options please?

Comment: If it works when you put the code: where order_id = 1; and it doesn't work with the Try#1 above then you must have another issue.  Maybe order_date is not defined as  DATETIME.  Please review your database structure.